# How to fetch multiple images from server and save and show them in iPhone app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am using following code for getting single image. But, how to do it for multiple images?

*This is my code :*

```
-(void)viewDidLoad 
{

 [super viewDidLoad];

[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(loadImageIntoMemory) withObject:nil];

}

-(void)loadImageIntoMemory {

    NSLog(@"Beginning download");
    NSString *temp_Image_String = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://www.thewavestore.com/appproductimage/"];
    NSURL *url_For_Ad_Image = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:temp_Image_String];
    NSData *data_For_Ad_Image = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url_For_Ad_Image];
    UIImage *temp_Ad_Image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data_For_Ad_Image];
    [self saveImage:temp_Ad_Image];
    UIImageView *imageViewForAdImages = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    imageViewForAdImages.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
    imageView.image = [self loadImage];
    [self.view addSubview:imageView];
}

-(void)saveImage:(UIImage *)image {

    NSLog(@"Saving");
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"DSC02077129HT41.5W20L24WT18.555RS28775.jpg" ];
    NSData* data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    [data writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
}

-(UIImage *)loadImage {

    NSLog(@"Got the data!");
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"DSC02077129HT41.5W20L24WT18.555RS28775.jpg" ];
    UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
    return image;
}
```

Please help to over come from this issues,if any good idea please suggest me.

Comment: use https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage for async process

Comment: you can save that images with the same way using different names (appending current date and time to name ) then you can iterate the images by using same way

Comment: @ANSHADR that means I have to write the code for each and every image? I have a lots of images on the server. Is there any way to do it only one common code for all images? Because, suppose if there are 100 numbers of images on my server, then I have to write separate code for each image. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: hi please check my answer you don't want to do it for every images , it will help you :)

Comment: @ANSHADR Okay! Thanks friend. I will check your code. I'll let you know then, if it works or not. :)

Comment: sorry you are downloading images from server rite? so better you save the images by appending an integer (or something unique) instead of date

Comment: yes, I am downloading images from server. Okay. But, Why to save the images by date or integer? I am bit confused here.

Comment: okei the problem is you need to save the images with different names so append something  with your commen image names like imagename_1.png, imagename_2.png  so we can retrive it properly

Comment: Ohh..I got it now. thanks a lot!

Comment: but there are lots of images on server having different names for changing it to the unique names..

Comment: please try my code no need to rename every image , just append the unique part to the name i think you solved the problem let me know..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First save  your images with unique names (i am using current time) and save this names to an array

```
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(chosenImage);
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains
    (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"];
    // save image with currentdate and time in the name
    NSString * imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"name_%@.png",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]];
    NSString *fullPathToFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageName];
    //add all the images names to the imagepath array
    [imagePathArray addObject:imageName];
    //write image into file
    [imageData writeToFile:fullPathToFile atomically:YES];
```

then retrive images from image path array

```
 for (NSString*path in imagePathArray ) {

            NSArray *filepart = [path componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
            NSString *filename = [filepart objectAtIndex:0];
            NSString *extension = [filepart objectAtIndex:1];

            NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains
            (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
            NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
            NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",
                                  documentsDirectory,path];

            //NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:filename ofType:extension];
            NSData *fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:fileName];
}
```

Comment: Hey buddy, one more question. This is very stupid one,but I am very new to iOS development.So my question is how to show these multiple images on the view at a time. means I am developing a small e-commerce app, and want show multiple images on a single view. I know about swiping feature but I just want to show multiple images using scrolling and when I click any image I want to display the description and price etc about that product/image? does I have to use multiple imageViews inside a main view or just I have to use a single image view? Please help. :)

Comment: Hi you can achieve this in diiferent ways and i think you are looking for somthing like flipkart or amazone app, I suggest you to use uicollectionview just go through this its easy to use http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-uicollectionview-tutorial/

Comment: Yes buddy!! I want to develop an app like myntra. and thanks for the reply. I'll definitely try your code.

Comment: hey, I tried the tutorial on Appcoda. It was very helpful. But, in this tutorial there are three columns of items in collection view. and I want to make only two columns close to one another like in myntra. How to do that?

Comment: do one thing set your demo cell width as half of collectionview width - your padding                       or try                                                                 -(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)view numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return 2;
}

Answer (score 0):

```
1. Store the server images in to array.

    NsMutableArray *arrImages=[[nsmutableArray alloc]init];

  2.Get the count of the array to run this in for loop.



    for(int i=0;i<[arrImages count];i++)
     {
            NSLog(@"Saving");
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent: arrImages[i]];
    NSData* data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    [data writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
     }
```

*To convert it to JPEG*

```
    NSData=UIImageJPEGRepresentation(UIImage,1.0);
```

Comment: Thanks mate! but, I am using .jpg image files. and the above method is for png file type I think "NSString *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)". Is I have to change this line for jpeg file type?

Comment: don't know bro ,i am not familiar with changing the .jpeg to .png,if u want tell me i will try @Vaibhav

Comment: just give uiimagejpegRepresentation(image);

Comment: here I get this when changed the code for jpeg : NSData* data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(UIImage *image, CGFloat compressionQuality); It is asking for the parameter for compression quality.

Comment: you need to convert the png to jpeg i am correct bro.

Comment: its ok bro...if my answer correct please mark it as correct may be it will help to others who suffer like this bro @Vaibhav

Comment: It's not going in the for loop. Control is jumps out of the loop and skip to the next iteration.